# What's the meaning of “a good downfall”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to know the meaning of “a good downfall” Is it a good, successful downfall/happy end or a properly deserved downfall-justice? So we like the stories about the King Shit who deserves a punishment OR do we like happy nedá, Especially when anybody ACTS like a King Shit? Is it also a funny metaphor of the shit softly falling down to “the cushion”?

The source: *Botticelli in the Fire*, page 4

> It is more of a downfall story
> And we all like a good downfall, don’t we?
> Especially when you’re the King Shit.
> And I was, for a time.

Comment: I read it as "a good *story* of a downfall", like "we all like a good tragedy" or "we all like a good romance".

Comment: And in this terms then we like a good tragedy especially about the King Shit OR someone who is a King Shit appreciates such a good tragedy even more?

Comment: The author might intend either meaning, or might intend both together for irony.

Comment: I think so… Thank you